# CSS join form input, select and submit elements into a single box

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to combine three form elements (input, select & submit) into a single bar for a search, it is obvious what I'm trying to do from this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0deLogqp/1/

html:

```
<div class="form-wrap">
   <form action="/search" method="get">
     <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." required class="search-box">
        <select>
        <option selected>All countries</option>
        <option>Australia</option>
        <option>Denmark</option>
        <option>USA</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Search" class="search-button">
    </form>
</div>
```

css:

```
/* combo search box */

form {
    margin:50px auto;
}

.form-wrap {
    display: inline;
}
.search-box {
    width:150px;
    padding:8px 15px;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
    border:2px solid #8FD926;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.search-button {
    position:relative;
    padding:6px 15px;
    left:-8px;
    border:2px solid #8FD926;
    background-color:#8FD926;
    color:#fafafa;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.search-button:hover  {
    background-color:#fafafa;
    color:#8FD926;
}

select {
    width:120px;
    padding:8px 15px;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2) url({% static 'images/caret.png' %}) no-repeat right center;;
    border:2px solid #8FD926;
    height:50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

(I know my css repeats, I unpacked it for testing).

Just in case there's any doubt, you can see a working example here: http://www.opencorporates.com

I want to stick to CSS only and avoid javascript (if possible).

Comment: Here - https://jsfiddle.net/0deLogqp/2/

Answer (score 0):

As provided by Paulie_D:

```
/* combo search box */
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
    margin:50px auto;
}

.form-wrap {
    display: inline;
    font-size:0; /* whitespace remover */
}

form > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
}

.search-box {
    width:150px;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
    border:2px solid #8FD926;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.search-button {
   position:relative;
   border:2px solid #8FD926;
   background-color:#8FD926;
   color:#fafafa;
   font-size: 28px;
   display: inline-block;
}

.search-button:hover  {
   background-color:#fafafa;
   color:#8FD926;
}

select {
   width:120px;
   background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2) url({% static 'images/caret.png' %}) no-repeat right center;;
   border:2px solid #8FD926;
   font-size: 12px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```